# where is user registration info?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have created a Silverlight Business Application by default. 
I am wondering where the user registration information is stored in Silverlight Business Application? How can I view it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Silverlight Business Application template uses the ASP.NET Membership service to store user information. Look at the UserRegistrationService.cs file in the web project.

You can learn about how to configure the membership service, including where data is stored, here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648345.aspx#paght000022_usingthesqlmembershipprovider